# Upgrade 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: keyboard

After upgrading 13.04 to 13.10 I have no keyboard. Fresh install of 13.04 and the keyboard is back, Fresh install of 13.10 and no keyboard. The laptop is an older LW40 1.8 Ghz 2Gb ram. A usb keyboard works fine but defeats having the laptops portability.
Oddly Fedora 19 has the same impact on the keyboard.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your problem but I just solved a 13.10 upgrade related keyboard issue by looking at this post:

[Keyboard not working 100% after Ubuntu 13.10 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360696/keyboard-not-working-100-after-ubuntu-13-10-upgrade?rq=1)

In this case the keyboard worked fine before login and in excel under wine but not in anything else.

This question also had a solution for a keyboard problem but it probably different than yours:

[Why did 13.10 break my custom keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361128/why-did-13-10-break-my-custom-keyboard-layout)