# After upgrade to ubuntu 13.10 keyboard input not working

Tags: unity, keyboard, 13.10

I just upgraded ubuntu to 13.10 but the keyboard input works fine only until I open whatever program is not part of Unity. ( No problems on the unity menu or at login )

Everything works fine under the "Flashback" ( no unity ) session.

Comment: I've noticed that some keyboard inputs work: '+' '-' '*' '/' and  'right Enter'.

I've unistalled Unity, but even without it, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

- Launch  **dconf editor**
- Open *Desktop* -> *ibus* -> and click on *General*
- Now check the box next to *use-global-engine* and *use-system-keyboard-layout*

Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your problem but I just solved a 13.10 upgrade related keyboard issue by looking at this post:

[Keyboard not working 100% after Ubuntu 13.10 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360696/keyboard-not-working-100-after-ubuntu-13-10-upgrade?rq=1)

In this case the keyboard worked fine before login and in excel under wine but not in anything else.

This question also had a solution for a keyboard problem but it probably different than yours:

[Why did 13.10 break my custom keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361128/why-did-13-10-break-my-custom-keyboard-layout)

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.